# How to extract the GPS coordinates of pins in open street map?

Tags: web-scraping, leaflet, openstreetmap

I want to extract the latitude and longitude of a set of about 400 pins in a open street map web page. I don't control the page and I don't need to do it more than once. Obviously, those data are public and free to use but I try to find an easy way to get those data instead of doing it manually.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: How do you put (or select) the pins in openstreetmap?

Comment: We can select the pin directly by clicking on it on the website.

Comment: But so (if you are centered), the URL will give you the coordinates. If you do manually (the pins), I think it is not much complex to extract manually the URL (and a small script you just extract the coordinates)

Comment: It is a little bit more complex. To perform this task manually, I have to : 
- Look a the Open street map widget on the website
- Clic on the desired pin/location
- Try to find the same location on another map and get GPS location from this new map. website here : [link](https://www.shlmr.fr/le-patrimoine)

Answer (score 1):

Checking with the FF inspector you should be able to see the script which contains the array of data starting with something like
`JSON_ARRAY_locations = [{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"TITRE\":\"4 EPICES\",\"VILLE\":\"SAINT-PAUL\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[\"55.3225112119793\",\"-20.9788005708745\"]}},`
Thus a matter of copy&paste.